# Python Suds complex types confusion

Tags: python, web-services, soap, suds

I am trying to use Python and the suds library to pull some data from a SOAP webservice that is housing my data. Unfortunately, I haven't done this through a SOAP web service before and am running into a bit of confusion. Here is the code that I have so far:

```
from suds.client import Client
wsdl = 'http://ws-argos.clsamerica.com/argosDws/services/DixService?wsdl'
client =Client(wsdl)
f1 = client.factory.create('ns0:baseRequestType')
f1.username ='xxxxx'
f1.password='xxxxx'
f1.programNumber='9999'
f1.nbDaysFromNow = '5'
print f1
print client.service.getObsCsv(f1)
```

Running this code gives me a generic WebFault error. As such, I am having a hard time debugging and finding out what I'm doing wrong. I suspect it has to do with the complex request types I'm trying to create with factory from suds. Anyone have any insight into what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Being a bit of a n00b myself, I think I can at least contribute by telling you that the signature of the getObsCsv() service does not call for a BaseRequestType object but for individual values which are all base types:

```
getObsCsv(xs:string username, xs:string password, xs:string programNumber, xs:string platformId, xs:string wmo, xs:int nbMaxObs, ns0:periodType period, xs:int nbDaysFromNow)
```

If it did, printing the client using:

```
print client
```

would yield a signature like this one in the list of methods:

```
getObsCsv(baseRequestType baseRequestType)
```

Basically, your service signature is NOT expecting a complex type, so I guess you're not calling your service correctly.